Can unlimited Duration spells be Dismissed?
Reading the remastered description of Peaceful Rest (Player Core p348), I see that when heightened to level 5, its duration becomes unlimited.  This seems like a useful way to keep someone's body viable until such a time as you can pay for resurrection magic.  However, there is no mention of the Dismiss action for this spell, and p419 of the same book says that the Dismiss action can "end an effect that states you can Dismiss it" (emphasis mine).
Does this mean that RAW you cannot ever voluntarily end an unlimited-duration spell once it has been cast?  Having to burn a fifth level Dispel Magic before using a sixth-level Raise Dead seems a bit excessive.

While it doesn't affect the larger question, I don't see anything in raise dead or peaceful rest that would require dispelling/dismissing the latter before using the former. Do you want answers about dismissing spells or raising dead?

@minnmass, i chose the title I did because I'm really interested in the requirement to dispel vs dismiss a spell when the duration is unlimited.  There may be other examples that would have been better, though Peaceful Rest is the spell that made me think about it.

Might make more sense if we change raise dead to 'raise undead' (create undead), once you go buy enough black onyx.

Not Inherently
As you've found, only some spells state that you can Dismiss them and not all permanent spells include that statement. There isn't a generic rule allowing all spells or even just permanent spells to be Dismissed, and this isn't new to the remastered rules.
So if you wanted to remove the spell you'd need to use something like dispel magic which is available to spellcasters of all traditions as a 2nd-rank spell. As this functions using a counteract check, you could even use the base 2nd-rank version to counteract the 5th-rank spell on a critical success, or much more reliably with dispel magic heightened to 4th-rank on just a success.
Also worth noting is that there's not much reason do remove the peaceful rest, as it specifically allows for things like raise dead with the advantage of keeping the corpse more easily revived.

Might be worth noting what happens to a spell if a target becomes no-longer-valid. Not directly related to the question, so might be a different question, but also seems related.

@Ifusaso'he-him' I'm not sure what would happen in that case, though it's an interesting related question.
